# Lifting question ban

Tags: support, post-ban

My account was banned after I asked 6 questions since early August, three of which were edited by a staff-like person.
I only posted some error messages and code that is not working for the CS50 course, and I have no idea what was wrong with this. I edited some of the questions after being banned, so can I now have the ban lifted?

Comment: Editing your previous questions to fix clarity issues would probably help a lot. Also spelling. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As per moderator Robert Harveys' comment "If you're trying to figure out how to get unbanned, everything you need to know is already present in the [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th); there's nothing else we can tell you."

Comment: At http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th the section "How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?" is (like the rest of that Q&A) worth a re-read.

Answer (score 9):

Looking through your questions on Stack Overflow, I noticed a few things that you could do to improve:

1. **Explain the problem you're solving**: In your questions [CS50, caesar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030659/cs50-caesar-solution) and [CS50, vigenere.c lack of argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037974/cs50-vigenere-c-lack-of-argv), you don't explain what you're trying to do, simply saying you're trying to do "caesar.c" and "check50". Note that most folks on Stack Overflow are not enrolled in your CS50 course, so you need to fully explain the programming problem you're trying to solve in the question itself for them to be able to help you. Likewise you don't explain the programming problem clearly in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317135/cs50-breakout-ball-movement and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324581/cs50-caesar-error-messages.
2. **Include reproducible examples for debugging questions:** If you are asking why your code is not working, you need to give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), meaning the minimal code needed for others to reproduce your problem. Note that you give very little to no code for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317135/cs50-breakout-ball-movement and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32324581/cs50-caesar-error-messages (certainly not enough to reproduce the problem in either case), and you don't specify the command-line argument used in [CS50, vigenere.c lack of argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037974/cs50-vigenere-c-lack-of-argv).
3. **Include language tags**: All of your questions appear to be about the C programming language. You should include that as the tag on your questions so they gain visibility to that community on Stack Overflow.

All these points are covered in the ["How to Ask" FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I would encourage you to review that guidance and edit your questions as next steps.